# Apache not able to start on Windows using XAMPP on any port

Tags: windows, apache, xampp, port80

I have tried all possible solutions:

1. Disabled IIS and other web services
2. Changed Listening port in http.conf and httpd-ssl.conf from 80/443 to 8080,8000,7777/4433,4434
3. Changed services and ports from the control panel itself.

Nothing seems to work. 
PS: I have Flask configured to port 5000 which is its default.

Comment: The steps you describe only help to release ports. Your service won't have any port conflicts if it can't even start. Did you check the logs? Windows Event log? Is the service itself running?

Comment: how do i do that?